# 1 ip address, 2 networks, 2 routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've been dealing with the following problem for a few days now and would kindly ask you for suggestions on what did I configured wrong.

In my Office I need 2 networks, one for my desktop & notebook & android, my camera and my printer, the other one for the whole office & colleagues.

1. Router (main router, for the whole office, works perfect)
   Static IP from the ISP with gateway and DHC (all correct)
   IP: 10.40.1.5
   Subnet: 255.255.255.0
   DHCP enabled, WiFi disabled

Cable from LAN port 1 on Router 1 to WAN port on Router 2

2. Router (only for me, LAN works, camera works, WiFi connects and sometimes works – very poor performance + terrible ping, loosing packets, than drops)
   Dynamic IP from Router 1 (10.40.1.20)
   IP: 10.1.40.5 
   Subnet 255.255.255.0
   Gateway: 10.40.1.5
   DHCP enabled, WiFi enabled

What should I do? If I try it with another router the problem is the same.
What have I missed?
I'm kind of new in this, but I educated myself to set it up and get it working, but I can't google up a solution for this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may be dealing with a few issues here and I'll try to address them.

Primarily, there may be QoS (Quality of Service) protocols in place on your office router that is designed to route the traffic in a method that has been set up and designed by your network admin. More important traffic is routed before less important traffic.
*How this effects you:* There are usually either group policies, or more deliberate methods that are used to say what traffic from your portion of the network is important or not. By introducing this new router, it is possible that you are just tossing out all of the QoS protocol messages and ending up as a default traffic which in most implementations is the lowest priority.

Second, since your main issue seems to be with the WiFi it is possible that it is coming into conflict with other signals or hotspots that are competing with it. The easiest solution in this case is to change what channel your WiFi is broadcasting on. To find an optimal channel there is plenty of software and hardware solutions available if your router does not perform this service by default.

The first issue might impact general performance on your mini network while the second would cover most WiFi issues. Depending on distance from the router, protocol used, environment (lots of cement around creating a rebound effect), or anything of the type you may be seeing a whole host of other factors that need to be addressed. All are worth looking into.